# AutoMapper .ProjectTo<T>() is causing some issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api

it may be duplicate and I did look at the other questions regarding this problem.

I am getting this error message in my code
"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

I feel like the .ProjectTo is causing some problem or am I missing something? I did not wrote the our entire BL(business logic) and they are using AutoMapper 4.2.1

[image]

here's the source code from that Execute block
[image]

If I make a simple query without those ApplyFilters ~~ etc .. e.g.

```
var query = (from dj in context.DJUsers select dj).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: Try an EF query with DateTime.ToString() without AM.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading EF. See [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2044) issue.